# Android sdkmanager --licenses freezes without any output

Tags: android, docker, android-sdk-tools

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM debian:9
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget unzip openjdk-8-jdk
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -O sdk-tools-linux.zip
RUN unzip sdk-tools-linux.zip
```

And when I ran

`docker run -it my-image /tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` it just hung there for a million years.

Then later I changed a few things around, and started getting this bizarre error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /proc/self/task/1/cwd/etc/ssl/certs/T??RKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa??lay??c??s??_H5.pem
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.toPath(FileSystemFileOp.java:284)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.isDirectory(FileSystemFileOp.java:169)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:225)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:201)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:123)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:725)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

I feel so helpless.

Answer (score 1):

You fool! Why are you extracting the android sdk zip into the root directory on your docker image? Move it outside the root, and everything will work!

```
FROM debian:9
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget unzip openjdk-8-jdk
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -O sdk-tools-linux.zip
RUN mkdir -p /sdk
RUN mv sdk-tools-linux.zip /sdk
RUN cd /sdk && unzip sdk-tools-linux.zip
```

`docker build . -t my-image && docker run -it my-image sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`